# Word which refers to a Position and Timestamp pair

Tags: single-word-requests, time, technical

I'm trying to find a term that refers to both a position and a timestamp associated with that position. "Position in time" is a common phrase. Are there more technical terms?

A position and timestamp would be expressed like this: a car was at 40.7484° N, 73.9857° W at Apr 23 15:08:16 UTC 2018

I found this question which has a lot of terminology for referring to these things individually: ["Position" is to "space" as what word is to "time"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438706/position-is-to-space-as-what-word-is-to-time)

Comment: The GPS numbering system already contains a timestamp within it. A "GPS number", therefore, actually conveys both time and position.

Comment: @NigelJ how so? 40.7484° N, 73.9857°  contains a timestamp?

Comment: The GPS system with which I am familiar has about 24 digits in it and includes location and time. I think 'spacetime' is unsuitable for surface of the earth co-ordinates, myself and wanders into the realms of relativity. 'Earth-time co-ordinates' might serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**spacetime coordinates**, where the timestamp alone could be referred to as **coordinate time**, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_time):

> In the theory of relativity, it is convenient to express results in terms of a **spacetime coordinate system** relative to an implied observer. In many (but not all) coordinate systems, an event is specified by one time coordinate and three spatial coordinates. The time specified by the time coordinate is referred to as **coordinate time** to distinguish it from proper time.

Attribution: "Coordinate Time." Wikipedia. April 10, 2018. Accessed April 23, 2018. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_time.

Answer (score 0):

**Timed location** is a phrase used in technical texts by computer programmers and in patents, as confirmed by an internet search, e.g.

> This sample shows how to use AVAssetWriterInputMetadataAdaptor API to write timed location metadata, obtained from CoreLocation, during live video capture.
>   (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCaptureLocation/Listings/README_md.html)

This question is also a [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432966/what-is-a-word-to-represent-a-location-in-time), but for flagging it as such, the other would need to have been answered.